# Posix Timer periodically skips ahead half of its period

Tags: c, linux, timer, posix

I have a task linked to a Posix Timer (timer_create()) that executes every 20 ms/50 Hz. Works fine for the most part, except every 334.5 seconds (approx.) the timer executes 10 ms early for the one cycle. For the next 334.5-ish seconds the intervals are all 20 ms again.

I've included the relevant code for configuring the timer. The application runs on a Gumstix Verdex Pro XL6P with Gumstix's default version of Linux. I also have it scheduled with FIFO scheduling algorithm.

My gut says this is a integer overflow issue. Maybe there's something else using the same signal? I've consistently been able to reproduce the skip, across executions and sessions on the board.

The issue's not a show stopper, but I would really like to understand why this is happening.

Here's the code for configuring the timer:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Create a timer which fires at the specified time and calls a timer event
// handler.
//
// handler : function to be called when the timer expires
// us      : number of microseconds to add to timer
// ms      : number of milliseconds to add to timer
// sec     : number of seconds to add to timer
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void createTimer(void (*handler)(void), uint32 us, uint32 ms, uint32 sec)
{
    struct sigaction sigact;
    struct sigevent sigev;
    timer_t timerid;
    struct itimerspec itval;
    struct itimerspec oitval;
    timer_info_t* newTimer = NULL;

    // Initialize signalNum.
    if (timers == NULL)
        signalNum = SIGRTMAX;

    if (signalNum < SIGRTMIN)
        exitWithError("no avaiable signals, unable to create timers");

    sigemptyset(&sigact.sa_mask);
    sigact.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigact.sa_sigaction = signalHandler;

    // Set up sigaction to catch signal
    if (sigaction(signalNum, &sigact, NULL) == -1)
        exitWithError("sigaction() failed, unabled to creat timers");

    // Create the POSIX timer to generate signo
    sigev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sigev.sigev_signo = signalNum;
    sigev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerid;        

    long ret = timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sigev, &timerid);

    if (ret == 0) 
    {
        // Prevent overflow in calculation of nsec below.
        if (ms >= 1000)
        {
            sec += (ms / 1000);
            ms = ms % 1000;
        }

        itval.it_value.tv_sec = sec;
        itval.it_value.tv_nsec = (long)(us * 1000L) + (long)(ms * 1000L * 1000L);

        // Configure it as a repeat timer.
        itval.it_interval.tv_sec = itval.it_value.tv_sec;
        itval.it_interval.tv_nsec = itval.it_value.tv_nsec;

        if (timer_settime(timerid, 0, &itval, &oitval) != 0)
            exitWithError("time_settime() error!");
    }
    else
        exitWithError("timer_create() error!");

    newTimer = (timer_info_t*)malloc(sizeof(timer_info_t));
    newTimer->timer = timerid;
    newTimer->handler = handler;
    newTimer->sigNum = signalNum;
    newTimer->next = NULL;

    // Check to see if this is the first time through.
    if (timers == NULL)
    {
        timers = newTimer;
        atexit(deleteTimers);
    }
    else
        lastTimer->next = newTimer;

    lastTimer = newTimer;

    signalNum--;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well I see at least two bugs in your code. One is that passing `&timerid` as the sigval for the timer event is completely invalid. It's the address of a local variable that will no longer be valid at the time the signal handler runs. It would be a lot better to pass a pointer to your `malloc`'d struct, which brings up the second "bug": you should be allocating this struct before starting the timer, not afterward. It may not have any ill effects the way you're using it, but it's generally a bad/bug-ridden pattern that could lead to bad race conditions in some usages.

Comment: Hm, well, by chance it still works. I'll get around to implementing your suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're using ntp, and that it's slewing the time at those intervals. You could try to use `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` instead, but according to http://juliusdavies.ca/posix_clocks/clock_realtime_linux_faq.html it might also be affected.

Comment: Ah, thank you for reminding me to change from realtime to monotonic, I'd meant to try that. The board has no network connection and thus shouldn't be adjusting the clock on me.